# Powershell running external batch

Tags: powershell

I am working on powershell script that finds and runs batch (`.cmd`) file.

`$batchFile = (Get-ChildItem $dest -recurse).Where({ $_.Name -like '*.deploy.cmd'},"First", 1) | % { $_.FullName }
Write-Output "This is a batch file $batchFile"`

The output of that is : `This is This is a batch file C:\Builds\01\2a4b7711\staging\_PublishedWebsites\TalentWebApp_Package\TalentWebApp.deploy.cmd`, which is what's expected.

But how do I actually run this command script from within powershell using script variable? 
`$batchFile /Y /M:devenv.outdomain.com` Tried several things and it didn't work.

We using Powershell 4. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Tried several things and it didn't work.* What exactly you tried, so we does not have to offer that again? And what *didn't work* means? `&$batchFile /Y /M:devenv.outdomain.com`

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's exactly what I was looking for and it works! I was trying to make `Invoke-Command` work and I never had to call external scripts from Powershell. Make it an answer and I will accept if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke command by it name stored in variable, you need to use invoke operator `&`. It is nothing specific to external scripts actually. Any PowerShell command can be invoked that way:

```
$CommandName1='Get-ChildItem'
$CommandName2='Where-Object'
$CommandName3='Format-List'
&$CommandName1 -File -Recurse|&$CommandName2 Length -ge 1gb|&$CommandName3 FullName,Length
```