# Execute a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following setup:

[image: Command Setup]

The last command is:
`$("$($InstallationPath)\$($ApplicationId)\$($ApplicationId).exe install")`

I want that to execute:

`C:\Services\OmStudioAdministration\OmStudioAdministration.exe install`

But it just prints the text of the command out. (Does not run the command.)

However if I copy that and run it, it does what I want:

[image: Command is Correct]

**How can I get it to run the command directly?**
(So I don't have to copy and paste it in and run it.)

NOTE: In case it matters, I am planning to run this as an Octopus Deploy script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell $($a) Has Unexpected Result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424797/powershell-a-has-unexpected-result)

Comment: `& "$InstallationPath\$ApplicationId\$ApplicationId.exe" install`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell running external batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997090/powershell-running-external-batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
& {$InstallationPath\$ApplicationId\$ApplicationId.exe install}
```

Script Blocks are generally easier to run than character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line by this one:

```
cmd.exe /c "$installationpath\$ApplicationID.exe" install
```